# Reset the pointValue when a player wins or loses a game of craps

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to reset the players point value once a player wins or loses but I cannot figure out the best method of approach with my current code. I have tried resetting the `pointValue.setText("0")` whenever the `round == 0` but that just sets the string to "0" and the `point` never re-initializes. I also tried adding a `win` and `lose` boolean value set to false, setting `win` or `lose = true` within the won or lost if statements, and then writing an if statement at the end of the `rollClicked()` method that would set the `point = 0`. None of my attempts have work and I am probably overthink it. For those that don't know how to play craps: If the sum is 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 or 10 on the first throw, that sum becomes the player’s “point.” To win, a player must continue rolling the dice until the point value is rolled. The player loses by rolling a 7 before rolling the point.

Here is the code from my MainActivity using the failed boolean attempt mentioned above

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // declarations
    private Button button1, button2;
    private ImageView dice1Image;
    private ImageView dice2Image;
    private TextView roll;
    private TextView point;
    private TextView results;
    private TextView betText;
    private TextView bankRollText;
    private String result;
    String betAmountString;
    String bankRollString;
    private Spinner bettingSpinner;

    int winNumber1 = 7;
    int winNumber2 = 11;
    int loseNumber1 = 2;
    int loseNumber2 = 3;
    int loseNumber3 = 12;

    int rounds = 0;
    int rollTotal = 0;
    int pointValue = 0;

    private int winsCounter = 0;
    private int loseCounter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initialize objects
        dice1Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDie01);
        dice2Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDie02);
        roll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRollTotal);
        point = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPoint);
        results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.howToPlayButton);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backToHomeButton);
        bettingSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.betSpinner);
        betText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBetAmount);
        bankRollText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBuyInAmount);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            results.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // get selected variable from spinner on HomeActivity
        TextView buyInText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBuyInAmount);
        buyInText.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("buyInAmount"));

        // query the data, put it in the string-array and use ArrayAdapter constructor
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.bet, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        bettingSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        bettingSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new function());

        // restores instanceState
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        // Capture button clicks
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg1)
            {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NewActivity.class);
                //myIntent.putExtra("buyInAmount",buyInAmountGlobalVar);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }); // end setOnClickListener

        // Capture button clicks
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg2)
            {

                // Start HomeActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }); // end setOnClickListener
    } // end onCreate method

    int d1, d2;
    int betInt, bankRollInt;
    boolean win = false;
    boolean lose = false;

    // initializes rollClicked method when ROLL button is clicked
    public void rollClicked(View v) {

        int dice1, dice2;
        betInt = Integer.valueOf(bettingSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        bankRollInt = Integer.valueOf(bankRollText.getText().toString());

        Random rand1 = new Random();
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        dice1 = rand1.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice2 = rand2.nextInt(6) + 1;

        // sets values for dice images
        if(dice1 == 1) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
            d1 = 1;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 2) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
            d1 = 2;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 3) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
            d1 = 3;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 4) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
            d1 = 4;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 5) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
            d1 = 5;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 6) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
            d1 = 6;
        }

        if(dice2 == 1) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
            d2 = 1;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 2) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
            d2 = 2;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 3) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
            d2 = 3;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 4) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
            d2 = 4;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 5) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
            d2 = 5;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 6) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
            d2 = 6;
        }

        // calculate sum of dice for each roll
        if (rounds >= 0)
        {
            rollTotal = sum(dice1, dice2);
            roll.setText(String.valueOf(rollTotal));
        }

        // win on first roll
        if((dice1 + dice2 == winNumber1 || (sum(dice1, dice2) == winNumber2)) && rounds == 0) {
            winsCounter++;
            bankRollInt =  bankRollInt + betInt;
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            win = true;
        }
        // lose on first roll
        else if(rounds == 0 && (sum(dice1, dice2) == loseNumber1 || sum(dice1, dice2) == loseNumber2 || sum(dice1, dice2) == loseNumber3)){
            loseCounter++;
            bankRollInt =  bankRollInt - betInt;
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            results.setText("House wins! You Lose.");
            lose = true;
        }
        // display round results if no win or lose on first roll
        else if(rounds == 0) {
            pointValue = sum(dice1, dice2);
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            point.setText(String.valueOf(pointValue));
            results.setText("Point established. It is " + pointValue + ". Roll Again.");
        }

        // lose if player hits 7 after first roll
        if(rounds > 0 && (sum(dice1, dice2) == 7)) {
            loseCounter++;
            bankRollInt =  bankRollInt - betInt;
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            results.setText("House wins! You Lose.");
            lose = true;
        }
        // player wins if roll = pointValue after first roll
        else if(rounds > 0 && (sum(dice1, dice2) == pointValue)) {
            winsCounter++;
            bankRollInt =  bankRollInt + betInt;
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            win = true;
        }
        // display round results if no win or lose after first roll
        else if(rounds > 0 && (sum(dice1, dice2) != pointValue && sum(dice1, dice2) != 7)){
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            results.setText("No one wins. Keep rolling Dice.");
        }

        rounds++;

        // reset point if player wins or loses
        if (win = true){
            point.setText("0");
        } else if (lose = true){
            point.setText("0");
        }
    } // end rollClicked method


    // calculate sum of dice
    public int sum(int num1, int num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    } // end sum method

    // clear board for new game
    public void resetGame(View v)
    {
        point.setText("0");
        roll.setText("0");
        results.setText("");
        betText.setText("10");
        bankRollText.setText("100");
        // reset counter
        rounds = 0;
    } // end resetGame method

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } // end onOptionsItemSelected

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
        // killed and restarted.
        result = results.getText().toString();
        bankRollString = bankRollText.getText().toString();
        betAmountString = betText.getText().toString();
        savedInstanceState.putInt("POINT_VALUE", pointValue);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("ROLL_TOTAL", rollTotal);
        savedInstanceState.putString("RESULTS", result);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("DIE_1", d1);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("DIE_2", d2);
        savedInstanceState.putString("BANK_ROLL", bankRollString);
        savedInstanceState.putString("BET_AMOUNT", betAmountString);
    } // end onSavedInstanceState method

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
        pointValue = savedInstanceState.getInt("POINT_VALUE");
        rollTotal = savedInstanceState.getInt("ROLL_TOTAL");
        result = savedInstanceState.getString("RESULTS");
        d1 =  savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE_1");
        d2 =  savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE_2");
        bankRollString = savedInstanceState.getString("BANK_ROLL");
        betAmountString = savedInstanceState.getString("BET_AMOUNT");

        roll.setText(String.valueOf(rollTotal));
        point.setText(String.valueOf(pointValue));
        results.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollString));
        betText.setText(String.valueOf(betAmountString));

        // resets dice image values for onRestoreInstanceState
        if(d1 == 1) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
        }
        else if(d1 == 2) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
        }
        else if(d1 == 3) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
        }
        else if(d1 == 4) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
        }
        else if(d1 == 5) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
        }
        else if(d1 == 6) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
        }

        if(d2 == 1) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
        }
        else if(d2 == 2) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
        }
        else if(d2 == 3) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
        }
        else if(d2 == 4) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
        }
        else if(d2 == 5) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
        }
        else if(d2 == 6) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
        }
    } // end onRestoreInstanceState method

    public class function implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long l)
        {
            // passes selected spinner variable to textViewBetAmount
            String betString = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            betText.setText(betString);
        } // end onItemSelected method

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
        {

        } // end onNothingSelected method
    } // end function inner class

} // end MainActivity class
```

I included the code in it's entirety so that you could see my declarations and `onCreate` method, but the issue is within the `rollClicked()` method. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the pointValue should = 0 after a player wins or loses because the round is over.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had the right idea of creating a boolean, but instead of using two boolean values I simplified things and created one. My original if statement to reset the point did not reset the round or include the `rounds++` counter, and I didn't not define my `else` statement (or in this case, what would happen if `win = false` or `lose = false`).

Old reset point if statement:

```
rounds++;

// reset point if player wins or loses
if (win = true){
    point.setText("0");
} else if (lose = true){
    point.setText("0");
}
```

New reset point if statement:

```
// reset point if player wins or loses else keep playing
if(resetPointValue == true) {
                rounds = 0;
                pointValue = 0;
            }
            else {
                rounds++;
            }
```

Here is the entire `rollClicked()` method:

```
private boolean resetPointValue = false;

    // initializes rollClicked method when ROLL button is clicked
    public void rollClicked(View v) {

        int dice1, dice2;

        betInt = Integer.valueOf(bettingSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        dice1 = rand1.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice2 = rand2.nextInt(6) + 1;

        // sets values for dice images
        if(dice1 == 1) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
            d1 = 1;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 2) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
            d1 = 2;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 3) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
            d1 = 3;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 4) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
            d1 = 4;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 5) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
            d1 = 5;
        }
        else if(dice1 == 6) {
            dice1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
            d1 = 6;
        }

        if(dice2 == 1) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
            d2 = 1;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 2) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
            d2 = 2;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 3) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
            d2 = 3;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 4) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
            d2 = 4;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 5) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
            d2 = 5;
        }
        else if(dice2 == 6) {
            dice2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
            d2 = 6;
        }

        // calculate sum of dice for each roll
        if (rounds >= 0)
        {
            rollTotal = sum(dice1, dice2);
            roll.setText(String.valueOf(rollTotal));
        }
        else {
            point.setText(String.valueOf(pointValue));
        }

        // win on first roll
        if((dice1 + dice2 == winNumber1 || (sum(dice1, dice2) == winNumber2)) && rounds == 0) {
            winsCounter++;
            bankRollInt = bankRollInt + betInt;
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            // display win result
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resetPointValue = true;
        }
        // lose on first roll
        else if(rounds == 0 && (sum(dice1, dice2) == loseNumber1 || sum(dice1, dice2) == loseNumber2 || sum(dice1, dice2) == loseNumber3)){
            loseCounter++;
            bankRollInt = bankRollInt - betInt;
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            results.setText("House wins! You Lose.");
            resetPointValue = true;
        }
        // display round results if no win or lose on first roll
        else if(rounds == 0) {
            pointValue = sum(dice1, dice2);
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            point.setText(String.valueOf(pointValue));
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            results.setText("Point established. It is " + pointValue + ". Roll Again.");
            resetPointValue = false;
        }

        // lose if player hits 7 after first roll
        if(rounds > 0 && (sum(dice1, dice2) == 7)) {
            loseCounter++;
            bankRollInt = bankRollInt - betInt;
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            results.setText("House wins! You Lose.");
            resetPointValue = true;
        }
        // player wins if roll = pointValue after first roll
        else if(rounds > 0 && (sum(dice1, dice2) == pointValue)) {
            winsCounter++;
            bankRollInt = bankRollInt + betInt;
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            // display win result
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resetPointValue = true;
        }
        // display round results if no win or lose after first roll
        else if(rounds > 0 && (sum(dice1, dice2) != pointValue && sum(dice1, dice2) != 7)){
            results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bankRollText.setText(String.valueOf(bankRollInt));
            results.setText("No one wins. Keep rolling Dice.");
        }

        if(resetPointValue == true) {
            rounds = 0;
            pointValue = 0;
        }
        else {
            rounds++;
        }
    } // end rollClicked method

    // calculate sum of dice
    public int sum(int num1, int num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    } // end sum method
```

This was definitely a case of overthinking and over complicating things.